# Angular 2 Service - Observable that uses a function with has callback function as argument

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable, angular-services

I have an Angular 2 service which consumes a SOAP Web Service. In order to do so, I use a Javascript SOAP client which has a callback function. I know that the result of a service method could be an`Observable`or a`Promise`, but I don't know how to go from the callback function back to the service.

Here is my current code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var SOAPClient: any;//<-- The library I'm using, it doesn't have types

@Injectable()
export class SoapService {
  connection_url: Map<string,string>;
  constructor() {
   this.connection_url = new Map<string, string>();
   this.connection_url.set('Example', 'http://localhost:8080/MYAPP_EJB/ExampleSvc');
  }

  consume(service_name: string, method: string, parameters?: Map<string,any>){
   var that = this;
   return new Promise<any>(function(resolve){
      var params = new SOAPClientParameters();
      if(parameters !== null){
        for (let parameter of parameters.keys()){
          params.add(parameter,parameters.get(parameter));
        }
      }
      //Below is the line where I use the function with the callback function argument (function(j)), where j represents the response from the Web Service
      SOAPClient.invoke(that.connection_url.get(service_name), method,params,true,
      function(j){
              return new Promise<any>(function(resolve){
                console.log('Web Service Answer: ' + j.answer.entry.value);
                return j;
              });    
      }); //End of SOAPClient.invoke()
    }); //End of promise of consume()
  }//End of consume()
}//End of class
```

What can I do to make consume() provide the Web Service response to a component? Will I need to introduce some modifications to SOAPClient?

Thank you.

### Edit: Solution

I used Robin's answer and worked with`bindCallback`(same idea as`fromCallback`, see [bindCallback](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback) for reference), using `SOAPClient.invoke` as argument for that function. The resulting function is the same as the original, but without the need of a callback function, returning a`Observable` instead, which I can subscribe and then resolve the promise of`consume()`.

The new code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from "rxjs";
declare var SOAPClient: any;//<-- The library I'm using, it doesn't have types

@Injectable()
export class SoapService {
  connection_url: Map<string,string>;
  invokeSoapClient: any;
  constructor() {
   this.connection_url = new Map<string, string>();
   this.connection_url.set('Example', 'http://localhost:8080/MYAPP_EJB/ExampleSvc');
   this.invokeSoapClient = <any> Rx.Observable.bindCallback(SOAPClient.invoke);
  }

  consume(service_name: string, method: string, parameters?: Map<string,any>){
   var that = this;
   return new Promise<any>(function(resolve){
      var params = new SOAPClientParameters();
      if(parameters !== null){
        for (let parameter of parameters.keys()){
          params.add(parameter,parameters.get(parameter));
        }
      }
      var invokeObs = that.invokeSoapClient(that.conexion_url.get(service_name), method, params, true);
      invokeObs.subscribe(r => {resolve(r[0])}); //r is the answer from SOAPClient invoke, I just needed the response part.
    }); //End of promise of consume()
  }//End of consume()
}//End of class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would eb to create a observable from your callback. You can easily create a observerable from a callback. [check this out](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromcallback.md)

Comment: You answer worked, I had to use`bindCallback` instead of`fromcallback`, I think its the same function, just with the name changed. Thank you @robin-dijkhof !